# Why does JSON_QUERY within CASE statement fail to remove escape characters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, json

It would seem that `json_query` fails to remove escape characters for the double quote character (") if the function is being applied within a `case` statement.

Example code below.

```
declare @data nvarchar(max);
declare @debug int = 0;

set @data = '{"id":10}';

set @debug = 0;
select
    isjson(@data) as 'validateData',
    @data as 'unprocessedSourceData',
    json_query(@data) as 'processedSourceData',
    case when @debug = 1 then json_query(@data) else null end as 'conditionallyProcessedSourceData'
    for json path, without_array_wrapper ;

set @debug = 1;
select
    isjson(@data) as 'validateData',
    @data as 'unprocessedSourceData',
    json_query(@data) as 'processedSourceData',
    case when @debug = 1 then json_query(@data) else null end as 'conditionallyProcessedSourceData'
    for json path, without_array_wrapper ;
```

Result from the first query:

```
{"validateData":1,"unprocessedSourceData":"{\"id\":10}","processedSourceData":{"id":10}}
```

Result from the second query:

```
{"validateData":1,"unprocessedSourceData":"{\"id\":10}","processedSourceData":{"id":10},"conditionallyProcessedSourceData":"{\"id\":10}"}
```

**Note the escape characters toward the end**: "`{\"id\":10}`"

1) Why would this be so?

2) How do I rework this query so that if `@debug = 1` then the `conditionallyProcessedSourceData` element contains valid JSON, and if `@debug = 0` then the element is `null`?

Comment: Please repost your solution as an answer and remove it from the question to follow the format of the site, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [JSON_QUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Returns a JSON fragment of type nvarchar(max).

and

> JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON
>   doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value.

So `for json path` escapes `nvarchar(max)` data unless the `nvarchar(max)` data comes from `json_query()`.

In your query the data comes from the case statement not directly from `json_query`.

The workaround you can do is to put `json_query` outside of the case.

```
json_query(case when @debug = 1 then @data else null end)
```

Incorporating this into your full script, so you can compare the different approaches, gives:

```
declare @data nvarchar(max);
declare @debug int = 0;

set @data = '{"id":10}';

set @debug = 0;
select
    isjson(@data) as 'validateData',
    @data as 'unprocessedSourceData',
    json_query(@data) as 'processedSourceData',
    case when @debug = 1 then json_query(@data) else null end as 'conditionallyProcessedSourceData', 
    json_query(case when @debug = 1 then @data else null end) as 'caseResultProcessed'
    for json path, without_array_wrapper ;

set @debug = 1;
select
    isjson(@data) as 'validateData',
    @data as 'unprocessedSourceData',
    json_query(@data) as 'processedSourceData',
    case when @debug = 1 then json_query(@data) else null end as 'conditionallyProcessedSourceData', -- This was the issue
    json_query(case when @debug = 1 then @data else null end) as 'caseResultProcessed' -- This is the solution
    for json path, without_array_wrapper ;
```